# Heroku Database availability by region for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, database, heroku

I am developing an app that uses Heroku database as a backend so i was wondering, would the app be available in all regions? because i read before that it would be only available in US and Europe?

Secondly, which plan should i start with when publishing the app into the app store? Will the free plan be enough for me?

Comment: "because i read before that it would be only available in US and Europe" please mention the reference of this information, where did you read that?

Comment: Hi Ahmad F, It was an article on the web that i can't find it anymore! that's why i am confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to your questions:

> would the app be available in all regions? because i read before that
>   it would be only available in US and Europe?

From the official website:

> Heroku Postgres is the SQL database service run by Heroku that is
>   provisioned and managed as an add-on. Heroku Postgres is accessible
>   from any language with a PostgreSQL driver including all languages and
>   frameworks supported by Heroku: Java, Ruby, Python, Scala, Play,
>   Node.js, PHP, Go, and Clojure.

As mentioned it's a *SQL database service*, for me, I find it -logically- that there is nothing related to availability of it in specific regions. I checked both [Mobile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/mobile) and [Database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/database) sections, I couldn't find any information about the region availability (and I hope it is true!), so, I assume that yes, it should be available in all regions.

---

> which plan should i start with when publishing the app into the app
>   store? Will the free plan be enough for me?

No, if you want to make an application and distribute it to the AppStore, you have to enroll to one of the paid [programs](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/), [fees](https://developer.apple.com/support/purchase-activation/) depends on what's the type of the enrollment, as  an individual or an organization.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much Ahmad. I don't think that i explained the second question very well. I just meant the Heroku database plans not the paid developer account. As i am confused which plan to choose for my app in terms of the storage and  the app scalability?

Comment: Oh! sorry for the useless answer then :) probably, I'll delete it

Comment: No it's not useless at all, you answered the first question perfectly and it helped me a lot. it's my fault i didn't explain myself very well :)